# How can I embed a video file when it's URL keeps expiring?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe, web

I'm trying to embed a video file, but the file's url keeps expiring. Is there anyway to refresh the link or somehow keep the video file embedded on the website? I was trying to embed the video using javascript, but iframe is allowed as well.

Comment: <video width="480" height="560" autoplay, controls>
  <source src="http://www1.streamratio.com:182/d/if74bczlv6cojhn2jjzzerijtfrqssye2vqiej5ta75cetzndbr5z6jt/Naruto Shippuden Episode 311.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

Comment: Thats the code I used. So HTML works as well, but the link expires after a while and the video won't play anymore.

Comment: The video doesn't belong to you, right? If it does, the streamration should give you a long lived link. Otherwise, you're not supposed to link to it, and they are enforcing that?

Answer (score 0):

Some hosting providers protect themselves from such embedding videos (so no one can avoid ads while downloading). You have to use the different hosting provider so you could acquire a static link to your video.

The best choice would be host it on your own ftp although it would increase the load on your servers.